# OpenTSDB Plotting internal stats

Tags: monitoring, opentsdb

I'm fairly new to OpenTSDB but I managed to set it up inside a docker container and connect Grafana to it.

Now I'm looking for a way to keep track of it's health. In particular, I would like to plot some of the metrics that come from the internal stats (e.g. tsd.rpc.received).

When I try to use them as a regular metric in the Graph panel of OpenTSDB I get a "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected exception".

I know I could connect the http api (/api/stats) to another tool to then send the metrics to cloudwatch or a similar app. But I was hoping for something that didn't involved adding more pieces to the solution.

In the documentation I found: "The Telnet style API also supports the "stats" command for fetching over CLI. These can easily be published right back into OpenTSDB at any interval you like."

Is this the recommended way to keep track of those internal metrics? Read from the stats api and then feed them back to OpenTSDB?

Answer (score 0):

After looking different alternatives I found that the best way to get the internal stats is either using the [tcollector](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/utilities/tcollector.html) util or injecting the output of the stats command back into opentsdb and using grafana to visualize the data.

Since in my particular case I don't want to install another component like tcollector, I'll feed the stats back to opentsdb as metrics in every node.

This is a small script I wrote to feed the stats back via the telnet api.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  sleep 5
  STATSINPUT=$(echo "stats" | nc 0 4242 -w1)
  while IFS= read -r line
  do
    echo "Feed: $line"
    INPUT="put $line"
    echo $INPUT | nc 0 4242 -w0
  done < <(printf '%s\n' "$STATSINPUT")
done
```